# Python. Получить минимальное и максимальное значение из файла

Tags: python, файлы, max, min

Требуется получить максимальное и минимальное значение из второго столбца и вывести соответствующую запись из 1 столбца.
Пример файла:

```
14:00:30|174
14:05:30|173
14:10:30|173
14:15:30|172
14:20:30|172
14:25:30|171
```

т.е пример: min: `171 (14:25:30)` max: `174 (14:00:30)`

Минимальное и максимальное значение получаю так:

```
import csv
with open('base.txt', "r") as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '|')
    minval = []
    maxval = []
    for i in data:
        minval.append(i[1])
        maxval.append(i[1])
print(min(minval))
print(max(maxval))
```

Как добавить вывод значения из 1 столбца, который соответствует минимальному и максимальному значению из 2 столбца?

Comment: Требуется, то... Делаю так... А вопрос то в чем? Чего ожидается узнать от сообщества не написано, ведь?

Comment: Подсказать, как добавить вывод значения из 1 столбца

Comment: гарантируется ли уникальность max и min значений правого столбца ? Если нет - какой должен быть вывод в случае, когда 2 и более min/max значений ?

Comment: Плохо получаете. Вам нужно всего два числа, а вы создаёте два ненужных списка. Если бы просто хранили в двух переменных два значения, то и другие данные были бы легко получить.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from itertools import tee
from operator import itemgetter
import csv


with open('base.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    payload_it = filter(len, reader)  # Выкидываем пустые строки (csv их вообще не должен содержать)
    min_it, max_it = tee(payload_it, 2)  # Разделяем один поток на 2 независимых
    key = itemgetter(1)  # Ключ для выбора минимума, максимума (то же самое, что и item[1])
    print(min(min_it, key=key), max(max_it, key=key))
```

Файл прочитается всего 1 раз, получите минимум и максимум (лексикографический) по второму столбцу.

Но это тоже плохой вариант, потому что в памяти будет храниться 2 копии содержимого файла (минимум и максимум ищутся в этих копиях). Поэтому лучше завести какие-то `minimum`, `maximum` значения и просто обновлять их при одном итерировании по файлу. Решение лучше я описал, но реализовывать его мне лень :)

---

Вариант с одним проходом и нахождением минимума максимума за проход без хранения всего содержимого файла в памяти на каком-либе из этапов:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import csv


def min_max(*args, key=lambda x: x):
    """
    Возвращает наименьший и наибольший элементы в итерируемом объекте
    или наименьший и наибольший из двух или более аргументов.

    :param args: Множество аргументов или один итерируемый
    :param key: Ключ, по которому будет выполняться сравнение
    :return: Наименьший и наибольший элементы
    """
    if len(args) == 1:
        iterable = args[0]
    else:
        iterable = args

    it = iter(iterable)

    try:
        min = max = next(it)
        min_key, max_key = map(key, (min, max))
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError('Empty sequence')

    for item in it:
        keyed = key(item)
        if keyed < min_key:
            min = item
            min_key = keyed
        if keyed > max_key:
            max = item
            max_key = keyed

    return min, max


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('base.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        payload_it = filter(len, reader)  # Выкидываем пустые строки (csv их вообще не должен содержать)
        print(min_max(payload_it, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('base.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '|')
    print(min(data, key = lambda x: x[1])
    print(max(data, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Либо:

```
with open('base.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '|')
    data = list(data)

    minimal = min(data, key = lambda x: x[1])
    maximum = max(data, key = lambda x: x[1])
    min_index = []
    max_index = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] == minimal:
            min_index.append(i)
        if data[i] == maximum:
            max_index.append(i)
    
    for i in min_index:
        print(data[i])
    for i in max_index:
        print(data[i])
```

Comment: А вы проверяли свой код?  `maximum = max(data, key = lambda x: x[1])
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: И все же попробуйте запустить свой код. Будете удивлены

Comment: Это не считая того, что 'object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()'

Comment: @Serg Bocharov все исправил

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('your.txt') as f:
    lines = [i for i in f]
    print(max(int(i.split('|')[1]) for i in lines if i != '\n'))
    print(min(int(i.split('|')[1]) for i in lines if i != '\n'))
```

Comment: Такая же проблема как и у Danis'a для второго прохождения уже нет данных

Comment: @SergBocharov edited

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам не нужно создать 2 списки `minval` и `maxval`, хватит один.
   Значит *1-ое улучшение вашей программы :*

   ```
   import csv
   with open('base.txt', "r") as csvfile:
       data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '|')
       val = []

       for i in data:
           val.append(i[1])
   print(min(val))
   print(max(val))
   ```
2. Вы можете использовать тот факт, что *кортежи сравниваются так, что в первую очередь сравниваются первые элементы кортежей* (и только если они равны, сравниваются и вторые, и т.д.).

   Значит, в список `val` добавляйте не только значения из второго столбца, но пару `(второй_столбец, первый_столбец)`:

   ```
   import csv
   with open('base.txt', "r") as csvfile:
       data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '|')
       val = []

       for i in data:
           val.append((i[1], i[0]))             # здесь разница
   print(min(val))
   print(max(val))
   ```
3. Когда вам не нравится формат вывода, вместо последних команд

   ```
   print(min(val))
   print(max(val))
   ```

   используйте например

   ```
   print(f"min: {min(val)[0]} ({min(val)[1]}), max: {max(val)[0]} ({max(val)[1]})")
   ```

   > ```
   >    min: 171 (14:25:30), max: 174 (14:00:30)
   > ```

   или то же самое более наглядно

   ```
   minval, maxval = min(val), max(val)   // minval = min(val);   maxval = max(val)

   min_num, min_time = minval            // min_num = minval[0]; min_time = minval[1]
   max_num, max_time = maxval
   print(f"min: {min_num} ({min_time}), max: {max_num} ({max_time})")
   ```